# How to make Amazon In-App Purchasing (IAP) 2.0 work with Android R8

Tags: android, obfuscation, in-app-billing, android-r8

It took a while after significant revenue loss to find out that [Android R8 code shrinker](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html) prevents Amazon In-App Purchasing (IAP) 2.0 from working.  Android Studio uses R8 by default now.  Fortunately, the following in gradle.properties seems to be able to stop R8:

```
android.enableR8=false
```

I fear R8 will be mandated in the future, and it will be a disaster. I am trying to find a way to make them compatible.
Someone posted [a similar question on Amazon's forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/205480/in-app-billing-not-working-since-android-studio-de.html) that is supposed to be the best place for such questions, but I have a feeling that Amazon has stopped supporting the forum because my recent two questions there have received no response from Amazon.

I have the following in proguard-project.txt that is used by R8

```
#amazon
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
-optimizationpasses 1
```

As my understanding, R8 ignores optimizationpasses. I suspect that is the cause.

**Edit(2019-05-30)**
The aforementioned script for proguard-project.txt is from [Amazon's document for In-App Purchasing](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-obfuscate-the-code.html)
The app's build.gradle has the following:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.Release

}
```

Comment: Hi, Hong. I'm one of the maintainers of [The Unofficial R8 Documentation](https://r8-docs.preemptive.com/) and might be able to help. Which ProGuard files, other than your proguard-project.txt, are you using in your Gradle build script (e.g., proguard-android.txt, proguard-android-optimize.txt, etc.)? Also, did Amazon recommend using that `-optimizations` rule? I didn't find it in the sample file given in their Android SDK, and it's worth noting that R8 doesn't support `-optimizations` rules either.

Comment: @PeterTefft Thanks a lot for lending a hand here.  To make the reading easier, I answered your questions by editing the post.

Comment: As this is a difference between Proguard and R8, could you file a bug on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:326788? The rules suggested by Anazom are very conservative, and R8 should not do much to the code in the `com.amazon` package, but apparently something goes wrong. Is there any indications in the logs for something going wrong inside the Amazon library when using R8? The fact that R8 is ignoring `-optimizations !code/allocation/variable` and `-optimizationpasses 1` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @sgjesse I am wondering if my post on Amazon forum with logcat entries provides any useful information: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/207075/purchasingservicepurchasesku-has-stopped-working.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proguard-android.txt` uses `-dontoptimize`, so it shouldn't be optimizing at all with ProGuard *or* R8, regardless of the number of `-optimizationpasses` specified. If you are interested, you can see the available default ProGuard files under `build/intermediates/proguard-files/`. `proguard-android-optimize.txt` is the one that would allow optimization.

At this point, given that R8's optimization doesn't seem to be on, I'm not sure if there's much of a workaround. I'd recommend that you file an issue with [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938), giving as much detail as you can to help them reproduce the issue. They are generally pretty responsive to issues like this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I found three files: files:proguard-android.txt-3.4.1, proguard-android-optimize.txt-3.4.1,proguard-defaults.txt-3.4.1. File android.txt-3.4.1 has -dontoptimize.  Not sure what the following in the official R8 document means:"R8 does not allow you to disable or enable discrete optimizations, or modify the behavior of an optimization. In fact, R8 ignores any ProGuard rules that attempt to modify default optimizations, such as -optimizations and - optimizationpasses. "

Comment: ProGuard does a lot of different optimizations, and it allows you to turn off individual optimizations. For example, that `-optimizations !code/allocation/variable` rule turns off the `code/allocation/variable` optimization, which "Optimizes variable allocation on the local variable frame," according to the [ProGuard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage/optimizations).

R8 doesn't allow you to pick and choose optimizations like that. You either turn all of them on or all of them off, maybe because it doesn't perform exactly the same optimizations as ProGuard.

Comment: I see. I think the official document is not clear about this.  I got the impression that some optimization was on, and you couldn't turn it off.    As my understanding of your explanation, I was not using R8 optimization at all because I was using android.txt-3.4.1.  I will wait a bit to see if Amazon's tech support staff can lend a hand here.  I have already contacted them.

Comment: @Hong did they actually fix it since then?

Comment: @Emil I think they have, but I have been avoiding R8, so I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Should work now with R8, add this to your main build.gradle dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.6.42'  //Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android. - Or any other version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:...'
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle

```
release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontoptimize
```

gradle.properties

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false
# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```

This works for me.

Comment: Could you join the discussion on this issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134766810

Comment: You have disabled R8.  We are trying to figure out how to use R8 with Amazon In-App Purchasing (IAP) 2.0.